# Android Java Upload Image and then wait to finish asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am working with AndroidStudio (Java) and there I Post data to URL and upload some images. This process is OK. The problem is that the task is async so it finish after verify other stuff.
This is the code:

```js
boolean ImgSubidasOK = true;
...

btnSubirFotosSistema.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            ...
              SubeFotografia(parametro1, parametro2);
              if (ImgSubidasOK){
                 //doSomething, ACTIVITY 1
              }
              else {
                  //doSomething, ACTIVITY 2
                   }
            ...
            }
}
...

public void SubeFotografia(final String parametro1, final String parametro2) {
...

    PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {
    @Override
    public void processFinish(String s) {
        if (s.contains("uploaded_success")){
            //IMAGE UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL
        }
        else {
             ImgSubidasOK = false;
             //ERROR UPLOAD IMAGE
             }
      }
    });
    String URLFinal = "https://URLASUBIRIMAGENES.php";
    task.execute(URLFinal);

...

}
```

So i would like to get the result of **processFinish** and then end the function 
 **SubeFotografia(parametro1, parametro2);**.
Because i have the issue that there is an error uploading the image and set the boolean **ImgSubidasOK = false** AFTER finishing **SubeFotografia**.
So i want to finish **SubeFotografia(parametro1, parametro2);** FIRST, with the **processFinish** and THEN check **if (ImgSubidasOK)**.

How can I do that with asynctask?. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
Changinf this line
task.execute(URLFinal);

For this:
String str_result = task.execute(URLFinal).get();